# There are not enough fields in the Structured type. Structured types must have at least one field C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a problem in my winforms, when I pass a data-table to sql-server through store procedure, i got an error same as title question.
Anybody can help me solve it ?

Method ExecDB in class dbHelper connect to sql and pass data :

```
public static DataSet ExecDB(string procName, params object[] obj)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conString);
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed) sqlCon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(procName, sqlCon);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(da.SelectCommand);
            if (da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Count - 1 != obj.Length) throw new Exception("Error");
            int index = 0;
            foreach (SqlParameter pr in da.SelectCommand.Parameters)
            {
                if (pr.Direction == ParameterDirection.Input || pr.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput)
                {
                    pr.Value = obj[index++];
                    //pr.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                }
            }
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Open) sqlCon.Close();
            return ds;
        }
```

Here's my DataTable will pass:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("NgayGiam", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("Tile", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Thang", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("MaMon", typeof(int));
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["NgayGiam"] =Convert.ToDateTime(i.SubItems[0].Text);
dr["Tile"] =Convert.ToInt32(tbxTiLeGiam.Text);
dr["Thang"] = twoMonth.Substring(twoMonth.Length - 2) + DateTime.Now.Year;
dr["MaMon"] = Convert.ToInt32(i.Tag.ToString());
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

And here's structure in SQL:

```
CREATE TYPE BANGGIAMGIA AS TABLE(
NgayGiam DATE NOT NULL,
Tile INT NOT NULL,
Thang VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
MaMon INT NOT NULL
)
```

And proc in SQL :

```
create proc sp_UpdateGiamGia
@temp as BANGGIAMGIA ReadOnly
as
begin
    Insert into GIAMGIA Select b.NgayGiam, b.Tile, b.Thang, b.MaMon from @temp as b
    Select * from GIAMGIA where MONTH(Ngaygiam) = Month(Getdate()) and year(NgayGiam) = Year(getdate())
end
```

I don't understand why it's. Pls explain to me.

Thanks.

Comment: You should look up the documentation for the SqlDataAdapter.Fill() method on MSDN, and read through until you see where you can simplify some of the code here.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn T_T

Comment: I still can pass each record to destinations table but I want to do it one times

Comment: Which line of code is giving error? Did you try setting pr.TypeName="BANGGIAMGIA" and pr.SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Structured ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya At da.Fill(ds). I tried

Comment: Did you verify that the value assigned to pr.Value is datatable only? and that data table has columns same as table type and at least one row in it ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks everybody, I found problem and solved it